# Network Collision Monitoring

Tags: networking, cisco

I want to monitor my network devices (router, switch) in our network for collisions. Can anyone please suggest any open source web application which can be used for the above purpose?

Comment: Unless you're running a non-switched network (yuck), collisions are largely a non-issue.

Comment: Collisions between the host and switch port can still be an issue if there's a duplex mismatch between the two. With each switchport being it's own collision domain this presents potential issues only for that connected host, as opposed to a hub network where collisions present potential issues for all connected hosts. Collisions in and of themselves don't neccessarrily create issues, that's why CSMA/CD exists. It's excessive collisions that create issues. http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/modules/ps2033/products_tech_note09186a008009446d.shtml#topic1

Comment: Makes me long for the good old days of thick- and thin-wire...  Ok, not so much "long for" as "shudder in revulsion at the thought of."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have hubs, you should have no collisions.

Any standard [SNMP monitor](https://serverfault.com/search?q=snmp+monitor) tool should be able to grab collision data from your routers or switches provided they are SNMP capable.

Search the site for network [monitoring tools](https://serverfault.com/search?q=network+monitor).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. The real problem is the network which I am diagnosing has an incoming 80Mbps speed but at the hosts the bandwidth received is just nearly 8Mbps. 

I suspect there are viruses in the network. Can anyone suggest how I can go about figuring out the exact cause ?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you're in a switched environment, in which case you shouldn't have collisions unless you've got misconfigured links between your hosts and your switch ports (host at half-duplex and switchport at full-duplex or vice versa), in which case you can monitor the switchport counters, if you have a managed switch that supports per port collision counters.